# vt100 terminal escape code issue

Tags: terminal, macos, xterm

When I ssh into any arista switch from my mac I get a mysterious `n` added to the prompt immediately on login.  After asking my coworkers about it I found out that it's about 50/50 where some also see the `n` and others do not.  I think I've tracked it down to a vt100 control character `ESC[5n` being sent by the arista switches.

I can see that with `less < <(ssh user@switch)` where I see:

```
*** MOTD ***
ESC[5nswitch.fqdn#
```

When I log in without less I see:

```
*** MOTD ***
switch.fqdn#n
```

My system:

- OS: macos ventura 13.5.2
- Terminal: iterm2 3.4.20 (also happens with terminal v 2.13 (447))

```
TERM=xterm-256color
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app #(also happens with TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal)
```

At least one of my coworkers who is not seeing the issue is also using `xterm-256color` and iterm2 as a terminal on macos.

When I log in with either of the following I **do not** see the `n`:

```
TERM=vt100 ssh user@switch
TERM=dumb ssh user@switch
```

However if I use `TERM=xterm` or log in normally I do see it.

I found this discussion describing the issue as well: https://rancid-discuss.shrubbery.narkive.com/gxEK2XnB/rancid-extra-characters-after-logging-in-arista-switches

---

I think it makes sense that it could be a vt100 vs xterm emulator issue but then it doesn't make sense why some of my coworkers don't see it.  Does anyone know what could cause this and if there are some other settings on my system I should look at to make it go away?

Comment: Not familiar with these switches. Are they Linux-based? More relevantly, do they have `terminfo`, and if so can you copy the definitions for `xterm-256color`, `vt100`, and `dumb` and decompile them with `infocmp`? I'd be looking for the `\e[n` sequence. What I'm thinking is that if you can find them you can override the system definitions with almost-identical ones that omit the appropriate characteristic. (I do this for `ti`/`te` values in my ~/.profile on several of my systems.) Let me know the result and if we've got a possible fix I'll see if I can expand this into an answer

Comment: @ChrisDavies: Looks like the arista OS is a fedora-based linux.  I know you can drop into a bash shell on them but I do not have the rights on these to do that unfortunately.

Comment: Note: escape sequences must finish with certain characters (which may not be used inside the sequence), so it shouldn't be a problem of terminal emulator (worse case: they will ignore the sequence).  OTOH `CSI 5 n` (status) should write `CSI 0 n` (OK). In any case: I suppose it is timing issue: terminals may change mode (hidden password to print text) which may cause problems with sequences (it is a bug, but timing bugs are difficult to notice).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: It happens for me 100% of the time and for others 0% of the time.  So would it be a bug with my terminal?  (Some other people are using the same version and not having an issue) or something else?

Comment: I think more on the server side: a second CSI is sent in between the first one. Check your profile scripts (on remote side). They may change some terminal settings, and surprisingly they wrote it skipping the buffer. Bugs that happens only on one person are difficult to debug... as you see. Many theories, but it is difficult to check them.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi There are no profile scripts on a switch.  It's also not just me getting it, it's about half and half some people get it and others don't.  The only difference between our accounts on the switch is our permission set.  I am a read only user but some admin users also see it and some read only users do not.

Comment: The switches are configured entirely by config management automation though including all user accounts so there is almost zero possibility for any user accounts to be uniquely different from another on the switch side.  This is also happening on thousands of different switches.